# How to complete time series with missing years and null values?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, dplyr

I am working on time data.
The data includes frequency values associated with years.

```
data <- data.frame(year = c(1789,1791, 1795),
               Freq =  c(12, 56, 67))
```

My problem:
Some years are missing.
What I expected:
I would like the missing years to be added in my data.frame with null values (with dplyr or base)

```
year Freq
1 1789    12
2 1790    0
3 1791    56
4 1792    0
5 1793    0
6 1794    0
7 1795    67
```

My idea: Create a table containing all the years including zero values, and merge it with my data ...

```
data2 <- data.frame (year = c(1789:1795), Freq = rep(0, 7))
```

Comment: the "idea" at the end of your question states a valid solution. I don't see the point in asking the Stackoverflow audience your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach using dplyr and left_join:

```
 library(dplyr)

 data <- data.frame(year = c(1789,1791, 1795),
               Freq =  c(12, 56, 67)) 


 data2 <- data.frame (year = c(1789:1795)) # , Freq = rep(0, 7)



 all<- left_join(data2, data)

 all
```

Comment: How is this different from @oshun's answer?

Answer (score 3):

Your idea makes sense.  This approach using `plyr` would work:

```
df1 <- join(data.frame(year = 1789:1795), df)  #Left join df years to all years 
df1[is.na(df1$Freq), "Freq"] <- 0              #Set NA to 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea, see my solution with dplyr